# group by order by max()

Tags: mysql, group-by, max, sql-order-by

I'm using MySQL.

The result I want, is to display the row with the highest 'time' where 'res' = 'hans', and group the 'frm'.

I am trying to fiddle around with GROUP BY, ORDER BY, MAX(time) - and I'm going no where.

My table: 'messages'

```
| frm  | res  | time |   msg    | opnd |
| poul | hans | 0916 | hi there |   1  |
| john | hans | 1033 | waz up   |   1  |
| hans | john | 1140 | new text |   0  |
| poul | john | 1219 | message  |   0  |
| poul | hans | 1405 | respond  |   0  |
| john | hans | 1544 | write    |   0  |
```

The result I want:

```
poul - hans - 1405 - respond - 0
john - hans - 1544 - write   - 0
```

The result I get:

```
poul - hans - 1405 - hi there - 1
john - hans - 1544 - waz up   - 1
```

I'm getting the correct 'time' but the wrong 'msg' and 'opnd'.

My code:

```
SELECT frm, res, MAX(time), msg, opnd
FROM messages
WHERE res = 'hans'
GROUP BY frm
ORDER BY time DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this.  One is to use a subquery and `join` back to the original table:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM messages m 
   JOIN (
      SELECT frm, res, MAX(time) maxtime
      FROM messages
      WHERE res = 'hans'
      GROUP BY frm, res) m2 on m.frm = m2.frm 
                      and m.res = m2.res
                      and m.time = m2.maxtime
ORDER BY m.time DESC
```

`Mysql` allows you to omit fields from the `group by` clause that are not used in aggregation (a mistake imo -- most other databases do not allow this behavior).  By allowing it, it just returns a random result though which is what you're experiencing.

---

Here'a another approach using an `outer join`, but I think the previous is easier to understand:

```
select m.*
from messages m 
   left join messages m2 on m.frm = m2.frm
                       and m.res = m2.res
                       and m2.time > m.time
where m2.frm is null 
   and m.res = 'hans'
order by m.time desc
```

- [Fiddle Demo With Both](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1aec91/1)

Comment: Thnx, this seems to be working. Never thought it would be this complicated.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you are grouping by one column, but you select several columns with it. As a result, for the other non-grouped by columns you will get just one of the results, not nececarily the one which belongs to the max(time) value.

you need something like:

```
select a.frm, a.res, b.max_time, a.msg, a.opnd from 
messages as a inner join
(SELECT frm, MAX(time) as max_time
FROM messages
WHERE res = 'hans'
GROUP BY frm) on a.frm = b.frm and a.time = b.max_time
ORDER BY time DESC
```